# What is a statistical test of whether a variable is uniformly distributed with kinks?

Tags: distributions, networks

I am trying to come up with a way to statistically test this question, and could use some input, as it's far afield from what I normally do. I have a hierarchical network, like this one:

[image]

And a centrality measurement of each node. What I want to do is test if the measurement for each "layer" (i.e. nodes 1 step from the diamonds, or 2 steps from the diamonds, etc) are uniformly distributed. The problem is that the layers aren't actually independent - the layers closer to the diamond will inherit some of the distortions from the layers below them, so what I actually want to test is that the distribution for layer X is *no more distorted* than the layer before it.

Any ideas how to go about that?

Comment: I think you need to more precisely define what you mean by "no more distorted"; but one idea is to look at median absolute deviations from the median of each layer.

Comment: @Peter Flom Fair point. When I say "No more distorted" I mean that the distribution of the variable is no less uniform in layer X than it was in the previous layer, which I'll call X+1. So for some hypothetical "uniformness score" where X+1 = 7, the score for X ~ 7.

Comment: I think that, to answer this precisely, you need a "uniformness score" that is not hypothetical. Then you could do some sort of test like bootstrap or permutation test.

Comment: That sounds about right. Time to go invent one of those, unless someone has ideas?

Comment: It would be useful if you could include plots of the distributions you're comparing.  But I suspect that the statistic (for comparing the distributions) won't be as big of a problem as the null distribution of the statistic.  Do you have just the one network?  Do you have a model for how the data arise, whether under the null or under the alternative?

Comment: There will be multiple networks, but under each the hypothesis being tested is that some nodes are more popular than others, under the null hypothesis that the popularity score is uniformly distributed among a given tier of nodes.